# onfocus() fails on a cloned element

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, clone, onfocus

I have a table where I add rows by cloning. However, I cant get onFocus to clear the text when a cell is clicked. Code fragment (I am learning Javascript by seat-of-pants since I has this dumped on me 2 weeks ago):

```
function AddRow() 
{
    var mytable=document.getElementById("newSystem");
    var rowClone=document.getElementById("sysrow").cloneNode(true);

    rowClone.cells[0].innerHTML='<input type="text" name="SysName[]"  value="host.myhouse.com" onFocus="this.value=\'\';this.onfocus=\'\';" />';

    myTable.appandChild(rowClone);
}
```

The original row from which the clone is derived is:

```
<tr  id="sysrow">
<td> 
    <input type="text" name="SysName[]" value="host.myhouse.com" onFocus="this.value='';this.onfocus='';" />;
</td>
</tr>
```

The onFocus on the original works fine. With the onFocus inserted to the clone script, it does nothing (no new row is inserted). When I remove the onFocus the cloned row is inserted but the text isn't cleared when focused.

Do I have something wrong or does onFocus not work with clones.

Comment: onfocus is a function defined somewhere else in the script? Could you post that code?

Comment: `this.onfocus=` ?...what purpose is does this statement have *inside* an inline attribute eventhandler of *`onfocus`???* Does `this.onclick` make sense if it's inside of `onclick`?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is no new row, because you have a typo at `myTable.appandChild(rowClone);`?

Actually, it should be `myTable.appendChild(rowClone);`

Comment: sorry about the typo .. I had manually retype between machines; troubled machine is on a private network.   if I remove the onFocus statement, the row insert works but the sample input stays in place when you select the cell. With the onFocus in place a new row is NOT inserted.